# Making Bootstrap's half slider carousel image responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I would like to adopt the half page background slider template from bootstrap (codepen in the below link), but am running into difficulties when resizing the page on desktop, as the background image does not resize accordingly. An explanation of the height and weight settings in the half-slider.css would be greatly appreciated.

http://codepen.io/kli96/pen/eBBmKB

The current implementation blocks out the top of the photo with landscape view on mobile and tablet devices, which is the reason I am trying to resize the half slider photo as the rest of the page is resized.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Half Slider - Start Bootstrap Template</title>


</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Half Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</header>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Half Slider by Start Bootstrap</h1>
            <p>The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The rest of the styles for this template are contained within the <code>half-slider.css</code>file.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})
</script>
```

And the corresponding css:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel {
    height: 50%;
}

.item,
.active,
.carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: Share your code in flunker or codepen for us to see the preview of ur trial. then we could suggest better.

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong link before - just added the code in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay You have probably two way solve this:

1) Make ur navbar-fixed-top class `position: relative`

OR

2) Add margin to ur carousel class `margin-top: 1%;`

Comment: Thanks! The position relative did the trick. I had to shift the carousel up to compensate, but on the landscape mobile view it looks perfect now.